# How can I auto populate a dropdown with years going into the future with php

Tags: php, date

I have a dropdown that I want to populate with a date starting from last year going up to 5 years in the future but I want it to update automagically every year with php.

Probably easier if I show what I want to end up with than trying to explain.

This Years dropdown should be

```
<select>
     <option>2012-08-31</option>
     <option>2013-08-31</option>
     <option>2014-08-31</option>
     <option>2015-08-31</option>
</select>
```

And nextYears dropdown should be

```
<select>
     <option>2013-08-31</option>
     <option>2014-08-31</option>
     <option>2015-08-31</option>
     <option>2016-08-31</option>
</select>
```

and so on.

Anybody got any ideas?

Comment: is the date and month 31-08 stored in database?

Comment: You should show us what you've tried, it is not a "give-me-solution-please" website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make a function like this

```
function getNextYears($fromDate, $nbYears)
{
    $time = strtotime($fromDate);
    $dates = array();

    for ($i=0; $i<$nbYears; $i++) {
        $dates[] = date('Y-m-d', mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m', $time), date('d', $time), date('Y', $time)+$i));        
    }

    return $dates;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions, learned something from them all but this one did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Increasing years?

```
for($i=date('Y'); $i<date('Y')+5; $i++){
    echo '<option>'.$i.date('-m-d').'</option>';
}
```

But better to play with [mktime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php)

Answer (score 1):

For adding an year, you can use

```
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('+1 year'));
```

for adding as many years

```
for($i=1;$i<=5;$i++)
{
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('+'.$i.' year'));
}
```

Using it with select box

```
<select name="years">
for($i=1;$i<=5;$i++)
    {
    ?>
    <option value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('+'.$i.' year')); ?>"><?php echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('+'.$i.' year')); ?></option>
   <?php
    }
    ?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

something like this may help you

```
<?php

$start_year = date('Y')-1;
$end_year   = $start_year+5;

for($i=$start_year; $i<=$end_year; $i++)
{
   echo '<option>'.$i.date('-m-d').'</option>';
}
```

?>

Comment: just want to know about "-08-31" how have you reached there .. is this fixed .. or from database ... or what  .. ?